# How to know if angular.js is done rendering the template for the current route

Tags: angularjs, behat

i would like to use Behat for testing my angular.js application. But the problem i'm experiencing is that when you go to a route and want to click on a link Behat doesn't know when the template is rendered, so sometimes it clicks while the content isn't available. Anyone that has experience with testing an angular.js application using Behat?

Or does anyone know how you can check in javascript if the template of the current route is done rendering? And how to check if angular.js is done bootstrapping the application on page load?

I know angular.js has ngScenario, but i want to use Behat because:

- The Gherkin language which is human readable
- Our backend is written in Symfony, so we can use the same framework for testing both

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 0):

The mink api has a method `wait` which allows you to pause the execution of your PHP contexts until your javascript application has finished processing 'something'.  There's a simple example in the docs: http://mink.behat.org/#basic-browser-interaction

```
$session->wait(5000,
    "$('.suggestions-results').children().length > 0"
);
```

In the example provided, the PHP context will be paused for up to 5 seconds until the list of suggestion results has been populated. You'll need to ascertain the equivalent javascript expression which will ascertain when your route has finished rendering.

We've had some trouble in the past using jQuery expressions and have reverted back to native browser methods such as `getElementById`.

You'll also need to use a mink driver capable of executing javascript. We use the `ZombieDriver` as it runs on the command line. There are a few alternatives which may suit you better.

http://mink.behat.org/#different-browsers-drivers

Comment: Just ran into a similar issue, and its been suggested that wait is not a real good solution as it is always fixed and you never know when the page is rendered. Solution at http://gediminasm.org/post/behat-sleep-alternative seems a lot better, need to see how to incorporate it in all the Behat rules